# Extending the Riemann integral to $(-\infty, \infty)$

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

It's natural to define the integral
$$\int_{0}^\infty f(x) dx := \lim_{M\to\infty} \int_{0}^M f(x) dx~~~~~~
~~~(*)$$

But it's not obvious how we should define the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx$$

One common approach is to say
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx := \int_{-\infty}^0 f(x) dx + \int_{0}^\infty f(x) dx~~~~~~~~~~~(A)$$
But we could as well define the integral as
$$\int_{0}^\infty f(x) dx := \lim_{M\to\infty} \int_{-M}^M f(x) dx ~~~~~~~~ (B)$$

Now let's take the identity function $f(x) = x$. Then

1. The definition (A) is helpless, since the expression is undefined.
2. $$\lim_{M\to\infty}\int_{-M}^{M} x dx = 0$$
3. $$\lim_{M\to\infty}\int_{-M}^{M+1} x dx = +\infty$$
4. $$\lim_{M\to\infty}\int_{-M}^{\sqrt{M^2+2}} x dx = 1$$

Basically, we can get the integral to be anything. On the other hand, there's no reason why one of the given definitions to be better than the other, why definition A should be favored over B. (we used a limit in $(*)$, why shouldn't we here?)

How should we then define the extension of the Riemann integral? Is there any way to avoid this complication?

Comment: The symmetric limit is the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value). (A) is equivalent to setting the improper integral to be
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx :=  \lim_{a \to \infty} \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_{-a}^b f(x) \, dx, $$
which, therefore, exists only when the limits can be taken in either order.

Comment: One thing that is nice about the Cauchy Principle value is that if $f(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \,dx=L<\infty$ exists in the improper sense i.e. $(A)$, (or how Chappers reformulated it), then the C.P.V. of the integral exists and is equal to the original integral. That is $\lim_{M\to \infty} \int_{-M}^M f(x) dx=L$.

Comment: Well, the first definition seems nice :) Can we say anything about *approaching the whole real line by any sequence of intervals*? This could give us a sense of *well-definedness* of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ of a function.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see why $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x\mathrm{d}x$ should not exist.
Since it is an odd function and we are integrating it over a symmetric interval it has to give zero, regardless of the fact that this interval is unlimited.
Is is just a purely mathematical matter, if the real problem concerning this integral results from a symmetric context, that is if the symmetry of the interval is linked to actual situations and the limit comes after, saying that it cannot exist would be just an annoying obstacle.

Comment: It being odd and the interval being symmetric isn't a convincing argument. What about $$\int_{-1}^1 \frac 1x \ dx$$?

Comment: $1/x$ is not even riemann-integrable in $[-\varepsilon _1, +\varepsilon_2]$ with $\varepsilon _1, \varepsilon _2 \in \mathbb{R}^+$.
However you are right, my answer lacked this additional restriction, i took for granted that the issue regarded just riemann-integrable functions on whichever limited real interval.